# Creating a new mean column in a loop by a custom function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, tidyeval

I wish to create a new column every time a grouped mean function is being called, for all the factor data types.

I am only able to replicate the decider result but only on a single factor variable **A**.

```
   df <- data.frame(
      target = c(1, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 1),
      A = c("A", "Z", "N", "A", "Z"),
      B = c("B", "Q", "G", "B", "T"),
      C = c("C", "Y", "C", "P", "Y")
    )

grouped_mean <- function(data, summary_var, ...) {
  summary_var <- enquo(summary_var)

  data %>%
    # Selects only factor data types and a target column
    select(which(map_chr(., class) == "factor"), !!summary_var) %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    # Over here I am not able to change column name, so that it yields Mean_A, Mean_B and Mean_C
    mutate(mean = mean(!!summary_var)) %>%
    ungroup()
}

grouped_mean(data = df, 
             group_var = A, 
             summary_var = target)
```

I tried looping it over:

```
map_df(df, grouped_mean(data = df, summary_var = target))
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Can't convert a `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object to function

Questions and inputs:

1. I am not sure how to make a function that dynamically changes name
   in a mutate function, from the name **mean** to **mean_A**,
   **mean_B** and **mean_c**
2. I tried the  map_df function to loop each element of the **df**, but unsuccessfully. The idea is to create new columns that are the means of the target feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit of a quirky solution but it should work for you (assuming you are ok with specifying `target` as the column you want the mean of). This just uses `mutate_if()` and uses subsetting with `tapply()` to get your means.

Then, it uses `rename_at()` to change the names to match your desired output.  If you want it to be lowercase you can wrap `gsub()` with `tolower()`

```
df %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, list(Mean = ~tapply(df$target, ., mean)[.])) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with("Mean")), ~gsub("(.*?)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", .))

   target A B C Mean_A Mean_B Mean_C
1       1 A B C    4.5    4.5   3.75
2       4 Z Q Y    2.5    3.5   2.50
3       8 N G C    6.5    6.5   3.75
4       9 A B P    4.5    4.5   8.00
5       2 Z T Y    2.5    1.5   2.50
6       1 A B C    4.5    4.5   3.75
7       3 Z Q Y    2.5    3.5   2.50
8       5 N G C    6.5    6.5   3.75
9       7 A B P    4.5    4.5   8.00
10      1 Z T Y    2.5    1.5   2.50
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Very interesting solution!

The dot in the tapply function, that stands for the Index, what exactly does the index do in this case?
Also, in the end, what does this do: [.] ?

Comment: It is a placeholder for the column in the anonymous function (indicated by the `~` in tidyverse syntax). So, it is iterating through the columns that meet the condition of `is.factor`. The brackets are subsetting the means from `tapply()` by name. It gets a little clearer if you run `tapply(df$target, df$A, mean)`, then `tapply(df$target, df$A, mean)[df$A]`. Think of the `.` as doing `function(.) mean(.)` with `lapply()`. You could also use `.x` to be a bit more explicit. Does that help clarify? If not, I can try to find some resources explaining it in more detail.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you for the solution and if you find some interesting resources, then please do share.

Comment: I will look and let you know--I know that they are referred to as lambda functions but I think that is language agnostic. There may be something specific related to tidyverse. Will post if I find!